# Проблема передать большое количество данных в сек (UDP)

Tags: c#, .net

Есть 2 компьютера, назовем их Компьютер А и Компьютер B.

Мне нужно передать звуковой файл формата PCM с Компьютера А на Компьютер В, отследить насколько точно передался файл и воспроизвести то, что прислал на Компьютер В на компьютере В.

Чтобы передать файл, использую

```
socket.SendTo(packet,0,count,SocketFlags.None,remoteEP);
```

из библиотеки System.Net.Sockets.

В итоге получается, что все передается точно -  я отслеживаю программой WireShark на Компьютере А и на Компьютере В. Однако то, что приходит на компьютер В, полностью не совпадает с исходным файлом, который передавался.

Программа, которая передает данные файла, открывает этот файл правильно, выставляет на передачу (Socket.SendTo) именно те байты, которые в исходном файле, но на выходе Компьютера А WireShark показывает совсем не то, то есть передается неправильно.

В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD:** Нет, файл передается в течение минуты по таймеру. Передаю по 400 байт.

Изначально в программе передавался звук с микрофона, как только буфер в 400 байт заполнялся, данные кодировались с помощью кодека G711 - в результате чего сжимались в 2 раза и передавались. То есть 200 байт. Надо будет попробовать передавать меньшее количество байт, может в этом проблема.

---

В общем, я протестировал передачу данных. Взял массив из 10 байт и передал.

**byte[] array = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a };

m_pUdpServer.SendPacket(array, 0, 10, m_pTargetEP);**

В итоге, на выходе компьютера А те же самые байты (0-10). Все правильно передается.
Или в цикле:

**byte[] array = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a };

while(true)

     m_pUdpServer.SendPacket(array, 0, 10, m_pTargetEP);**
 Тоже все передается без ошибок.

А вот код, который я использую для передачи звукового файла по таймеру.

```
 private void m_pTimer_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        uint sent_data = 0;

        while ((sent_data <= (BUFFERSIZE / 120)) && ((num * RAW_PACKET) + sent_data  < BUFFERSIZE))
        {
            uint bytes_count = ((BUFFERSIZE - (RAW_PACKET * num)) > RAW_PACKET) ? RAW_PACKET : (BUFFERSIZE - (RAW_PACKET * num));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes_count];
            Array.Copy(ReadBuffer, num * RAW_PACKET, buffer, 0, bytes_count);
            num++;
            // Send and read next.
            m_pUdpServer.SendPacket(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bytes_count), m_pTargetEP);
            sent_data += bytes_count;
        }

        if ((num * RAW_PACKET) + sent_data == BUFFERSIZE)
        {
            m_pTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
        m_pPacketsReceived.Text = m_pUdpServer.PacketsReceived.ToString();
        m_pBytesReceived.Text   = m_pUdpServer.BytesReceived.ToString();
        m_pPacketsSent.Text     = m_pUdpServer.PacketsSent.ToString();
        m_pBytesSent.Text       = m_pUdpServer.BytesSent.ToString();
    }**
```

Здесь 120 - количество частей файла, которые передаются в течение каждого вызова таймера. Файл длится 1 минуту. То есть, таймер вызывается 2 раза в секунду.  Каждый раз, когда он вызывается, ему нужно передать (BUFFERSIZE / 120) файла, где BUFFERSIZE - общий размер файла. И он в цикле передает эту часть файла по RAW_PACKET(RAW_PACKET = 400 байт).
sent_data - общее количество байт, переданных в течение каждого вызова таймера.
num - общее количество отправленных пакетов.
ReadBuffer - общий массив, в котором хранятся все байты файла.

Я поставил точку останова на строку
m_pUdpServer.SendPacket(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bytes_count), m_pTargetEP);
Программа зашла в нее, посмотрел значение переменных, элементов массива и запустил программу далее. И так несколько раз. То есть я вызывал строку
m_pUdpServer.SendPacket(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bytes_count), m_pTargetEP);
несколько раз с задержкой в несколько секунд.
И получилось, что все передается правильно.

А когда я просто запускаю таймер, который без перерыва передает данные в цикле - получаются неверные результаты.
Сам файл достаточно большой - около 50 Мб, то есть в секунду надо передать около 800 000 байт.

То есть, получается, что код программы в функции таймера не справляется с требуемой нагрузкой и поэтому происходит неверная передача байтов?

Comment: _"выставляет на передачу (Socket.SendTo) именно те байты"_ -- при передаче с А они приходят на В без изменений?

Comment: в WireShark компьютера А при передаче те же самые пакеты и байты, что и в WireShark на Компьютере В при приёме.

Comment: есть прямой порядок, например: ". N E T", и тоже самое в обратном порядки: "N . T E". попробуйте передавать байты в другом порядке.

Comment: Little Endian  и Big Endian (менять местами байты)?

Comment: я просто смотрю на содержимое звукового файла и на байты, которые отправляются и не вижу никаких закономерностей(

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста код приема данных.

Comment: EndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,0);
                                int received = socket.ReceiveFrom(buffer,ref remoteEP);

Comment: Если отослать строку "1234567890", заведомо меньшую, чем размер пакета - что приходит?

Comment: @lindstorm: А почему вы пользуетесь низкоуровневыми сокетами, а не хотя бы `TcpListener`'ом? (Только не говорите «ради эффективности», не поверю.)

Comment: Мне нужен UDP. Моя задача - как можно больше пакетов данных передать, не дожидаясь ответа от принимающей стороны.

Comment: UDP 1. Не гарантирует доставку последовательно. 2. Гарантирует тихое помирание пакета без сообщения об ошибке

Comment: Еще раз, покажите код, это сильно облегчит поиск решения. Передаете весь файл одним сендом?

Comment: UDP не гарантирует **вообще ничего**. Если вы передаёте файл через UDP, не жалуйтесь, что на том конце приходит непонятно что — вы сами выбрали UDP, сами и виноваты.

Comment: @VladD Я знаю отличную шутку про UDP, но не факт, что она до вас дойдет

Answer (score 4):

Причина в том что когда срабатывает таймер в "плавание" почти одновременно уходит множество пакетов, очередность и доставка не гарантируется. По этому на выходе получаем 800 кб перемешаных данных.

Чтобы хоть как-то заработало нужно добавить идентификатор пакета и на принимающей стороне предусмотреть склеивание пакетов в правильном порядке и пропуск пакетов которые за некоторое время так и не дошли. Также очень рекомендую избавится от таймера и отправлять данные равномерно, синхронизируясь по времени. Также придется добавить контрольные суммы.

Под "синхронизируясь по времении" я имел ввиду поток который спит пока мы опережаем график и отправляет данные если настало время или мы отстаем.
Определить график отправки не сложно, так как известен битрейт.

Еще раз повторюсь и посоветую посмотреть в сторону стандартных решений.

Comment: Если пакеты приходят не по порядку, но в пакете все байты расположены правильно, без путаницы, тогда можно склеить пакеты, сортировать их. Но если в самом пакете байты хаотично расположены. И по поводу синхронизации - потоки использовать? Или что?

Comment: Если есть пакет а внутри данные которые например не дают правильную контрольную сумму то пакет выкидывается.

Answer (score 3):

Нечего переизобретать RTP. Этот протокол специально предназначен для передачи медиаданных в сетях с негарантированной доставкой и нестабильностью скорости. Так что берите готовый протокол и не теряйте время.

Comment: Полностью согласен, несмотря на то что звучит грубовато